# Use UPDATE statement with SUBSTRING for result updation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to update the status basing upon another column's first index value that resides in the range of dates. What is the proper way of using that.

```
UPDATE `store_results`
SET `results_status` = "unpublished"
WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`results_trigger_on`,' ',1) AS resultdate
    FROM `store_results` HAVING resultdate BETWEEN '15/09/2018' AND '20/09/2018')

SELECT *,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`store_results_trigger_on`,' ',1)) AS resultdate FROM `store_results` WHERE `store_results_status` = '$status' HAVING  resultdate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' ORDER BY `store_results_id` DESC
```

This seems not to be working. What's wrong in it or what needs to be modified! Also included the working select STATEMENT

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than 'seems not to be working'? Do you get errors, or the wrong result? If so, what is it, and what's wrong?

Comment: This is an error, but when used with SELECT statement it works fine. Don't know how to achieve what i wanted. This is the working SELECT statement
SELECT *,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`store_results_trigger_on`,' ',1)) AS resultdate FROM `store_results` WHERE `store_results_status` = '$status' HAVING  resultdate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' ORDER BY `store_results_id` DESC, and i want in the same condition the UPADTE statement to work.

Comment: It looks like you are storing unnormalized date information as text.  Please include sample data for your table, and the expected output.

Comment: what is the key between two table

Comment: Some sample data would be very helpful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i stored the date in form of VARCHAR, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

The following update should work:

```
UPDATE store_results
SET results_status = 'unpublished'
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(results_trigger_on, ' ', 1), '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN
        '2018-09-15' AND '2018-09-20';
```

You should avoid storing unnormalized date information as text going forward, to avoid messy queries like this one.

Comment: No as i said all the dates are stored as VARCHAR format and as d/m/Y form

Comment: @LittleGyaani I updated my answer per your feedback.